# Set the jruby jvm without changing the JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, jruby

Is it possible to change the jre used by jruby without changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable in Windows?

I am running jruby with the jruby.exe but couldn't find any parameter for the jre path. I don't want to change my JAVA_HOME (which is Java 1.6) because it will affect other applications on my machine, but I just want to specify to Jruby to use the Java 1.7 jre otherwise I am getting errors.

I am using jruby 1.7.23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you `set JAVA_HOME` in the cmd line or "hard-code" it in a *jruby.bat* launcher (discouraged but if you must ...) that would only change it for the process run from that particular cmd line.